# Retrieving object's entries in order

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object `{5:"James",1:"John", 3:"Jade"}`. When reading its entries it should read it in below way `{1:"john",3:"Jade",5:"James"}`, without modifying the actual object.

Comment: Did you try simply searching “sort object keys in JS”? Duplicate of [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key).

Comment: Well, as your key are numeric in this case, when you create the same object on developer console, you will see it automaticaly enumrate them in proper order, but if the keys are string then result would have been different.
Just try this out on console.
let a = {
  5: "James",
  1: "John",
  3: "Jade",
  10: "ten",
  7: "seven"
};
console.log(a);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sort the object

```js
const obj = {5:"James",1:"John", 3:"Jade"};

const result = Object.fromEntries( Object.keys(obj).sort().map((key) => {
  return [key, obj[key]];
}));

console.log(result);
```